# What are the names of the special children in Supernatural?

Tags: supernatural

The only ones I remember are Sam, Jake, Ava, Andrew, and Lily. I know there are more but I just can't remember the rest..

Answer (score 2):

[Supernatural wiki](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/Special_Children) listed them all who appeared on the show with their special powers:

> - Andy Gallagher – Mind control
> - Ansem Weems / Weber – Mind control
> - Ava Wilson – Premonitions
> - Jake Talley – Superhuman strength
> - Lily Baker – Necrokinesis
> - Max Miller – Telekinesis
> - Sam Winchester – Premonitions
> - Scott Carey – Electrokinesis
> - Rose Holt – Unknown (apparently never infected)